# IONIC ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module '../home/home.module' Error: Cannot find module '../home/home.module'

Tags: ionic-framework

Firstly, when i login the error show:

**ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module '../home/home.module'
Error: Cannot find module '../home/home.module'**

Here the code for the error part:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {Routes, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { MenuPage } from './menu.page';

const routes: Routes =[
  {
    path: '',
    component: MenuPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'home',
        loadChildren: '**../home/home.module#HomePageModule**'
      }, /* '../home/home.module#HomePageModule' */
      {
        path: 'tabs',
        loadChildren: () => import('../tabs/tabs.module').then( m => m.TabsPageModule)
      }, /* '../tabs/tabs.module#TabsPageModule' */
      {
        path: 'status',
        loadChildren: '../status/status.module#StatusPageModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'butiranmaklumat',
        loadChildren: '../butiran-maklumat/butiran-maklumat.module#ButiranMaklumatPageModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'tabs/butiranmaklumat',
        loadChildren: '../butiran-maklumat/butiran-maklumat.module#ButiranMaklumatPageModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'butiranpekerjaan',
        loadChildren: '../butiran-pekerjaan/butiran-pekerjaan.module#ButiranPekerjaanPageModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'tabs/butiranpekerjaan',
        loadChildren: '../butiran-pekerjaan/butiran-pekerjaan.module#ButiranPekerjaanPageModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'butiranpasangan',
        loadChildren: '../butiran-pasangan/butiran-pasangan.module#ButiranPasanganPageModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'tabs/butiranpasangan',
        loadChildren: '../butiran-pasangan/butiran-pasangan.module#ButiranPasanganPageModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'maklumattanggungan',
        loadChildren: '../maklumat-tanggungan/maklumat-tanggungan.module#MaklumatTanggunganPageModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'tabs/maklumattanggungan',
        loadChildren: '../maklumat-tanggungan/maklumat-tanggungan.module#MaklumatTanggunganPageModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'sejarahpermohonan',
        loadChildren: '../sejarah-permohonan/sejarah-permohonan.module#SejarahPermohonanPageModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'tabs/sejarahpermohonan',
        loadChildren: '../sejarah-permohonan/sejarah-permohonan.module#SejarahPermohonanPageModule'
      }
     /* {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'home',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }  
      */    
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [MenuPage]
})
export class MenuPageModule {}
```

So, i try to delete ".." on the bold line and write back ".." . and it can successfully login. 
But the other error show:

**ERROR TypeError: datas.pr_master_pengguna is not iterable**

Here the code for this part:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Provider} from '../../providers/provider';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {Storage} from '@ionic/storage';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.page.scss'],
})
export class LoginPage {

  LoginPengguna:string;
  KataLaluan:string;
  task:any[];

  constructor(
    private provider:Provider,
    private  router:Router,
    private storage: Storage
  ) { }

  login(){
    return new Promise(resolve =>{
      let body = {
        LoginPengguna:this.LoginPengguna,
        KataLaluan:this.KataLaluan
      };

      this.provider.postData(body, 'login.php').subscribe(data => {
       // console.log(data);

       if(data['user']){
        this.storage.set('IdPengguna', data['user'][0]['IdPengguna']);
        this.router.navigate(['menu/tabs/tabs/home']);
        }else {
          alert("Login failed");
        }
      });
    })
  }

}
```

but for this error, i just refresh it and data show.

So i try to terminate and run it back. and the error still show the same. it just like cache in my code.
Hopefully u guys can help.

Answer (score 0):

Error was this part

```
children: [
      {
        path: 'home',
        loadChildren: '**../home/home.module#HomePageModule**'
      }, /* '../home/home.module#HomePageModule' */
```

change it

```
  // Full path including `src` at the start:
    loadChildren: '/home/home.module#HomePageModule'
```

or this:

```
 // Relative path from the `app-routing.module.ts` file:
    loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomePageModule'
```